# Create a Fuzzy Duplicate Key to Sum Rows with Fuzzy Matches (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

So I have a table where I have identified fuzzy matches and an amount. I want to be able to summarize the amount by this common key.

My Data looks like this:

| Name | Match1 | Match2 | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jame | James | Jim | 1 |
| Jame | James | Jim | 2 |
| Mike | Mikes | Miike | 3 |
| James | Jame | Jim | 4 |
| Jim | Jame | James | 5 |
| Mikes | Mike | Miike | 6 |
| Miike | Mike | Mikes | 7 |

```py
data = {'Name': {0: 'Jame',
  1: 'Jame',
  2: 'Mike',
  3: 'James',
  4: 'Jim',
  5: 'Mikes',
  6: 'Miike'},
 'Match1': {0: 'James',
  1: 'James',
  2: 'Mikes',
  3: 'Jame',
  4: 'Jame',
  5: 'Mike',
  6: 'Mike'},
 'Match2': {0: 'Jim',
  1: 'Jim',
  2: 'Miike',
  3: 'Jim',
  4: 'James',
  5: 'Miike',
  6: 'Mikes'},
 'Amount': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

##### What I'd like my resulting table to look like:

| Key | Name | Match1 | Match2 | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jame | Jame | James | Jim | 1 |
| Jame | Jame | James | Jim | 2 |
| Mike | Mike | Mikes | Miike | 3 |
| Jame | James | Jame | Jim | 4 |
| Jame | Jim | Jame | James | 5 |
| Mike | Mikes | Mike | Miike | 6 |
| Mike | Miike | Mike | Mikes | 7 |

So I can summarize my data like this:

| Name | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Jame | 12 |
| Mike | 16 |

Comment: So the `Key` will match either the `name`, the `match1` or the `match2`?

Comment: That's right, the key will match any of these items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initially have the list of keys for your dataframe, you can do this.

```
mylist = ['Jame','Mike']

df['Key'] = [j for i in df.to_numpy() for j in mylist if j in i]

df.set_index(df.columns[-1]).reset_index(inplace=True)

    Key   Name Match1 Match2  Amount
0  Jame   Jame  James    Jim       1
1  Jame   Jame  James    Jim       2
2  Mike   Mike  Mikes  Miike       3
3  Jame  James   Jame    Jim       4
4  Jame    Jim   Jame  James       5
5  Mike  Mikes   Mike  Miike       6
6  Mike  Miike   Mike  Mikes       7
```

And then, you can do `groupby.sum` to get your desired output.

```
df.groupby('Key')['Amount'].sum().reset_index()
    Key  Amount
0  Jame      12
1  Mike      16
```

### Update

To obtain the key through the dataframe, you can use the `process.extractOne` in `fuzzywuzzy` to compare the matching percentage of every element in a row. If it's less than the threshold, we will update the key.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

key = [df.Name[0]]

for row in df.to_numpy():
    for i in row:
        if 50 < process.extractOne(i, key)[1]:
            break
        else:
            key.append(row[0])
            break
            

key
Out[65]: ['Jame', 'Mike']
```

Comment: I don't have a list of keys. I think the logic I would like is that it would take the first name where the matches take place and all subsequent items were all the items match it would take the first 'Key'.

Comment: IIUC, for Jame, the first time it appears and has the matches is on index 0, whereby Mike is on index 2. So we use these two names as the keys

Comment: Yes, but I want the code to define the keys not myself

Comment: hey @David54321 You can find the key using this code ```key  = set()
for row in df.to_numpy():
    if not key:
        key.add(row[0])
    found = False
    for k in key:
        if k in row:
            found = True
            break
    if not found :
        key.add(row[0])```

Comment: See if it works for you now?